# multiply the integer within a combination of string and integer in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example if we have a string like:

```
duration = "2.days"
```

how can I multiply this 2 with 3 within "2.days" and get:
 "6.days"

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to be using the helper methods:

```
2.days
# => 2 days

2.days * 3
# => 1036800
```

If you mean to manipulate the string:

```
duration = "2.days"
p = duration.split('.')
[ p[0].to_i * 3, p[1] ].join('.')
# => "6.days"
```

Comment: Actually I have:{:run_at => 2.days.from_now)} and want to multiply 2.days with 3 to get {:run_at => 6.days.from_now)}

Comment: `(2.days * 3).from_now` and `(2*3).days.from_now` will both produce the correct answer. If all you have is a time, then `Time.now + (future_time - Time.now) * 3` should triple the time into the future.

Comment: There is schedule_date (any date selected by user) and want to add duration like: 2.days etc with schedule_date. {:run_at => schedule_date + duration)}. It works fine but want to multiply an integer(3 or any) with duration.

Comment: I've spelled out three different methods there, so surely one will work. What is the "duration" stored as?

Answer (score 2):

Following code is useful if you want to multiply string like "5.months 2.days 3.minutes"

```
"5.months 2.days 3.minutes".gsub(/\d+/){|s| s.to_i*3}
=> "15.months 6.days 9.minutes"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to start with a string and result in a string, then regex is usually the best way.

```
"2.days".sub(/\d+/){|s| s.to_i*3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(duration.split('.').first.to_i * 3).to_s + '.days'
```

Comment: There is schedule_date (any date selected by user) and want to add duration like: 2.days etc with schedule_date. {:run_at => schedule_date + duration)}. It works fine but want to multiply an integer(3 or any) with duration

Answer (score 0):

```
duration = "2.days" 
duration[0] = (duration[0].to_i * 3).to_s
p duration # => "6.days"
```